# SEO impact of hosting static HTML on Amazon S3 vs. webserver

Tags: seo, web-hosting, amazon-s3, files, static

**Scenario:** Updating a static HTML file hosted on AWS S3 bucket.

I read that a file (including static HTML) cannot be updated on AWS S3 bucket. Existing file needs to be deleted, new file with same name needs to be created with new content added to old.

*"there is no 'partial blob' updating. You need to upload the entire new copy of the file"* (source https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9517198/can-i-update-an-existing-amazon-s3-object)

So was thinking out loud, how will that impact SEO? (Basically whole static HTML file will be deleted and a new one will be created.)

Will the search engine crawl the newly created AWS HTML page (with old name) again in exact same manner had it been a scenario of static HTML file hosted on a webserver (e.g. Apache server)?

Comment: It won't affect SEO. When you update a file you are in effect deleting and creating a new file anyway. There's no real difference here.

Comment: John, if the OP's site is extremely popular, and he deletes a file and waits too long to make the next file uploaded for any reason (including unexplained lengthy internet connection failure), then odds of website guests seeing the "page not found" or similar message go up. However, if he has a good connection and he makes the changes very quickly, then there is really no affect to SEO. Also, I don't understand why the OP would try to host an HTML file on a website specifically designed for remotely storing files.

Comment: I sometimes see s3 hosted files on the `s3.amazonaws.com` domain name.   I've never used s3 myself, so I don't know if you can attach your own domain name to a bucket, but hosting images on Amazon's domain could really change Google Images rankings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may be misunderstanding the concept, here.

Files on S3 cannot be *modified*, but they can be *overwritten*, and overwriting a file does **not** require deleting the old file, first.  You simply upload a new file with the same name.

The old file does not go away unless and until the new upload is complete and successful.  A failed or partial overwrite of an existing object in S3 will never corrupt the existing object.  If an overwrite fails due to any cause, such as losing your Internet connection during the upload, S3 discards the failed upload and the original object remains untouched.

Any downloads of the old file are allowed to finish, and downloads of even large files are not interrupted or corrupted if the file is overwritten with a download in progress.

There's no SEO impact potential, here.